# How to make ESlint automatically fix the problems it has identified when saving the file?

Tags: eslint

ESlint detects problems in my .js/.ts/.tsx files on VScode but I want it to fix those automatically.

I have the eslint and prettier extensions installed. Prettier does format my code but not the eslint problems.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps worked for me.

1. Make sure, your have eslint installed globally on your local machine.
   You can check via `eslint -v`. If this command returns error, install eslint with `npm install -g eslint`.
2. You can enable automatic fixing by setting "editor.codeActionsOnSave" to "source.fixAll" in your settings.json file.